# Dynamically render folder view in Route in Laravel

Tags: laravel

Let's say I have a folder like this

```
  resources/views
       paths
          path1
             index.blade.php
             registration.blade.php
          path2
             index.blade.php
             registration.blade.php
```

And my route

```
   Route::get('/paths/{$path}, function(){
       return view('paths/{$path}/index);
   });
```

This doesnt work if I do this

```
 localhost.com/paths/path1
```

Any Idea how make it work? Doing this in controller is more preferred.

Ok I already fixed that in closure before train_fox answered. I preferred that in controller

```
public function index(Request $request, $path)
{
 $paths = [
        'CD1',
        'CD2',
        'CD3',
    ];
    foreach($paths as $path){
        if($path === request()->segment()){
            return $this->paths = $path;
        }
    }
   return view('paths/'.$this->path.'/index');
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Did you read your code properly?

Answer (score 1):

Your route should be:

```
 Route::get('/paths/{path}', function($path){

   return view("paths/{$path}/index");
 });
```

Hope it will serve your purpose.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to pass variable to closure:

```
Route::get('/paths/{$path}, function($path){
   return view('paths/{$path}/index);
});
```